# Fitting a curve through 3 points, each of dimension 6

Tags: interpolation, curve-fitting

I have the following data I generated from an experiment (input is column A, output is column B):

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 100 | (0.7, 0.7, 5, 15, 0.01, 0.0055) |
| 500 | (0.55, 0.3, 2, 5.5, 0.03, 0.0042) |
| 1000 | (0.75, 0.15, 1, 3.25, 0.03, 0.0035) |

I want to use this data to find the values in column B for, let's say, 300 in column A. Finally, I want to compare these values that I got for 300 to the ones I get after I run my experiment and get these parameters for 300 and make sure they are close.

I was thinking along the lines of curve fitting or interpolation of some sort, but I don't quite know how to begin. I do realize that there would be a unique "circle" that passes through these points in the 6th dimension, but I am not sure how to do that. Another option I thought about was to just fit separate curves for each parameter in column B and bring them together. Which is a better way to go about doing this? Also, any pointers towards code or libraries that would help will be appreciated.